# Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's render method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, bundling-and-minification, npm-install

I have written a self-contained component and it works properly If I am running this component as a stand-alone component. I'd like to release this component as NPM module so I can share this component. In my sample application I've defined the path to the module in my package.json and it's being pulled down by NPM fine. I am using webpack for bundling and it successfully builds the package but when I run the code in the browser I get

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a
>   ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component
>   that was not created inside a component's render method, or you have
>   multiple copies of React loaded

I had spent a full day and tried few hacks but I am not able to found the exact root cause of the issue?

Comment: You could be using multiple versions of react. Check your modules in node_modules and make sure

Comment: I have checked the react version and there is no issue with react version. I am using ref in my react component for dom traversing.

Comment: I think Dominic meant that you may have multiple instances of react. Your post seems to indicate the component is stand-alone - do you mean it includes react and renders itself? If so, that might be the problem if you're then using it inside a react project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your webpack config use this in the external configuration like:

```
output: {
    path: __dirname + "/dist",
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    // library: 'hello-007',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
  },
  externals: [{
    'react': {
      root: 'React',
      commonjs2: 'react',
      commonjs: 'react',
      amd: 'react'
    }
  }, {
    'react-dom': {
      root: 'ReactDOM',
      commonjs2: 'react-dom',
      commonjs: 'react-dom',
      amd: 'react-dom'
    }
  }],   
   module : {
    loaders : [
      {
        test : /\.js?/,
        loader : 'babel'
      }
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

There is other way to have a ref in code which is also solving this issue. use ref like this

```
<div className="nav-window-content"
          ref={(node) => this.menuList = node}>

and for getting the reference use 
this.menuList
```